# Can Folder Shortcuts be explored from within SHBrowseForFolder?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2005, winapi

I'm trying to resolve an issue that I brought up at the end of the investigation into [`SHBrowseForFolder` and folder shortcut browsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851831/shbrowseforfolder-and-shortcuts): I cannot figure out how `IFolderFilter`'s member function `ShouldShow` should work to filter out everything but folders and folder shortcuts.

I haven't found much documentation on this and my current solution doesn't work, please see below:

Here's what I have for the function:

```
HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE ShouldShow(IShellFolder* sf, LPCITEMIDLIST pidlFolder, LPCITEMIDLIST pidlItem)  
{  
    HRESULT resultCode = S_OK;  

    ULONG attributes = 0UL;  

    if (SUCCEEDED(sf->GetAttributesOf(1, &pidlItem, &attributes)))  
    {  
        if (attributes & SFGAO_FOLDER)  
        {  
            resultCode = S_OK;  // Yes, I see the folders
        }  
        else if (attributes & SFGAO_LINK)  
        {  
            // How do I determine if it is a folder AND let the end-user explore them?
            // I ran the code with the resultCode = S_OK just to see what happens
            // it displays the shortcut folders, but I cannot explore them. When I
            // "expand" them (click on the plus-sign-box), nothing happens.
        }  
    }  

    return resultCode;  
}
```

Can anyone tell me what code I need to add to filter out everything *but* folders and folder shortcuts (and still be able to explore the folder shortcuts)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to me that your function always returns S_OK. Is that your intent?

Comment: No, that's not the ultimate solution.  I couldn't find out how to determine if what I have is a shortcut folder or not, so I just return S_OK for everything until I can figure out how to return S_OK correctly. I think that the `if (attributes & SFGAO_FOLDER)` portion is correct, but the `else if (attributes & SFGO_LINK)` is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way.